# Ruby on Rails Authlogic password not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, authlogic

I am trying to implement Authlogic. Registering is fine, it enters all the necessary details into my database..

.. but when I try to log in, it gives me the error:

> 1 error prohibited this user session
>   from being saved
>
> There were problems with the following
>   fields:
>
> Password is not valid

My password *is* valid. I am not sure what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds familiar to me but my memory isn't jarred... Perhaps you can post your migration, and controller/model/view for logins?

Comment: I second SingleShot's statement.

Comment: What makes you so sure your password is valid? Obviously it isn't. That is, some validation is adding errors. Are you aware of the built-in default validations in authlogic, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it was because I was migrating from Restful authentication.
The issue was: 
 Restful authentication puts a 40 char cap on password-salt and crypted-password.
 the hashes generated by authlogic are larger than that.

```
class RemovePasswordSaltCap < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :password_salt, :string, :limit => nil
    change_column :users, :crypted_password, :string, :limit => nil
  end
end
```

Found this answer in the fine manual.

[the fine manual](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/003bd21bdde1e65efec7b47d7e38e954d97e6aa4/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/RestfulAuthentication/Config.html#transition_from_restful_authentication-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

In your user model, try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validate_password_field = false
  end

end
```

Then try to log in again. If that works, then you will know that the authlogic default validations were tripping you up.

You can also try

```
valid_password?(attempted_password, check_against_database = check_passwords_against_database?)
```

with the console

Answer (score 1):

If upgrading to authlogic the default crypto_provider has changed from `Sha512` to `SCrypt` so it might be a case that passwords are broken. Check out the authlogic 
[readme](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic#upgrading-to-authlogic-340)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and my problem was that I wasn't using the REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY key value that I previously used with restful authentication.

I added the key value and everything works :)